# Suggestion for bedroom furniture for a small home?

Tags: layout, bedroom

I have a very small home ( about 50 m<sup>2</sup> ).  Currently in my bedroom I have 2 desks and 3 bookshelves, but there is no space for a bed ( my wife wants to kill me :D ). The bedroom size is about 12 m<sup>2</sup> and the public room is about 18 m<sup>2</sup>.

What can I do for my bed?

Comment: sleep under the desk.

Comment: Or over it - a loft bed may work better. Although it may have a college dorm room feel.

Comment: @Doresoom now i use this way :D

Comment: Do you have room along a wall for a murphy bed to fold down at night?

Comment: -1 because this question has many elements of decorating advice and "shop for me" which encourage subjective and spam answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get some ideas from [Resource Furniture](http://www.resourcefurniture.com/space-savers) designs. I have a feeling they're a little pricey (you've got to request quotes), so you may just be able to look at some concepts they have and make a DIY version.

Specifically, if you're looking to have a desk and a bed in the same room, [here's a good option](http://www.resourcefurniture.com/space-savers/queen-space-saving-beds/ulisse-desk):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: thats awesome but how much is Useful life of Ulisse Desk or morphy bed?

Comment: Most furniture manufacturers offer a warranty with their products. For example, the cheapo couches I bought a few years ago have a lifetime warranty for frame damage, but only had a one year warranty for upholstery. Something 'upscale' like this bed should definitely come with a reasonable warranty, and if it doesn't I'd steer clear.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of combining desk and bed space, another way to go is to look for ways to combine your bookshelves into your desk. Especially try to find a corner, possibly somewhat round desk with large shelf space.

If you have a dresser, it can be easily replaced by beds with large drawers as the base.

Put shelves up directly on the walls at a decent height to save floor space. You could mount them above and around the desk. I've seen tables built into walls and even some drawers / cabinets. If you can reduce all your current furniture's actual floorspace while keeping the storage space, there should be plenty of room for a bed =)